# Containerized Angular build recompiling every time

Tags: angular, docker

### Context

Recently I have been trying to containerize my Angular build, because I am deploying the frontend together with the backend in a single image. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# Build frontend
FROM node:16 AS node-build
WORKDIR /app

COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build

# Build backend
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet-build
WORKDIR /app

COPY backend ./
RUN dotnet restore Api
RUN dotnet publish Api -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dotnet-build /app/out .
COPY --from=node-build /app/dist/film-portal wwwroot/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

### Problem

The Dockerfile above perfectly builds the image in question, and it works like a charm after deployed. However, the build takes more time than I'd like. Let me explain:

- `npm install` is only run if either `package.json` or `package-lock.json` have changed. This is great and saves time.
- `npm run build` is run whenever the frontend code is touched. This is of course intended behavior, but it will recompile the Angular library code every time instead of caching the compiled result (as is the case when you do `npm run build` from your local shell).

I am looking for a way to cache the results of compiling the angular library code, so `npm run build` only has to build my own code (taking less time to complete). In imaginary syntax, I need something like the following in my Dockerfile for the frontend stage:

```
FROM node:16 AS node-build
WORKDIR /app

COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm compile-angular

COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build
```

Here `npm compile-angular` would compile the angular bits only when `package.json` or `package-lock.json` change, instead of every time I touch some file in the frontend code.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no command in the Angular CLI to specifically compile the Angular library code, leaving aside the user code. Also, all tutorials I read fail to mention the problem of recompilation, so maybe I am missing something here. Still, I can hardly imagine I am the first one to come across this problem and I assume there must be at least a workaround. So, to summarize:

1. Is there a way to avoid recompiling the Angular library code in a dockerized setup like mine?
2. If not, is there at least a workaround, maybe by performing the build step outside of Docker?

Answer (score 0):

After long searching I found about [Issue 17017](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17017) in the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/) repository. [One of the comments](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17017#issuecomment-609921036) to that issue mentions that there is a hack to trigger ESM compilation: `./node_modules/.bin/ngcc --properties es2015`. With that knowledge, I modified my Dockerfile and it works like a charm, no longer recompiling the Angular library code upon every change to my own code:

```
# Build frontend
FROM node:16 AS node-build
WORKDIR /app

COPY frontend/package.json frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

# Hack to make sure the angular modules are compiled at this stage
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/ngcc --properties es2015

COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build

# Build backend
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet-build
WORKDIR /app

COPY backend ./
RUN dotnet restore Api
RUN dotnet publish Api -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dotnet-build /app/out .
COPY --from=node-build /app/dist/film-portal wwwroot/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```